# joomla 2.5 pagination always set start limit to 20

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I developed my own joomla 2.5 custom component for displaying data table in front-end.It contain filtering,paging and sorting.When navigate via paging it always shows only first 20.
Is there any way to override limit of a query which generate on function getListQuery().

My populateState method is

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
        // Initialise variables.
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
        $filter_order = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter_order', 'filter_order');
        //$filter_order = JRequest::getCmd('filter_order');
        $filter_order_Dir = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter_order_Dir', 'filter_order_Dir');
        //$filter_order_Dir = JRequest::getCmd('filter_order_Dir');

        'filter_region', '');

        $this->setState('filter_order', $filter_order);
        $this->setState('filter_order_Dir', $filter_order_Dir);


        // List state information
        $limit = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $app->getCfg('list_limit'));
        $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

        $limitstart = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');
        $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart);

        parent::populateState();
    }
```

Constructor method is

```
    function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();


            //Get configuration
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $config = JFactory::getConfig();

            // Get the pagination request variables
            $this->setState('limit', $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_jointcm.limit', 'limit', $config->getValue('config.list_limit'), 'int'));
            $this->setState('limitstart', JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int'));
    }

List query method is

protected function getListQuery() {
        // Create a new query object.
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
 //code goes here...
..............

return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around and taking a look at the source code of the JModelList class, I realized that problem is with 
\libraries\joomla\application\component\modellist.php file ,method name public function getItems(),line number 115.

I changed it to

```
public function getItems()
    {
        // Get a storage key.
        $store = $this->getStoreId();

        // Try to load the data from internal storage.
        if (isset($this->cache[$store]))
        {
            return $this->cache[$store];
        }

        // Load the list items.
        $query = $this->_getListQuery();
        //$items = $this->_getList($query, $this->getStart(), $this->getState('list.limit'));
$items = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('list.limit'));

        // Check for a database error.
        if ($this->_db->getErrorNum())
        {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
        }

        // Add the items to the internal cache.
        $this->cache[$store] = $items;

        return $this->cache[$store];
    }
```

Change was

```
$items = $this->_getList($query, $this->getStart(), $this->getState('list.limit'));
```

to

```
$items = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('list.limit'));
```

It works fine.

Comment: Your edit makes sense, but I wonder why it works fine for Joomla articles and other components like K2 that use the same function.

Comment: Changing the core is a bad idea, see my answer for reasons why you may be having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `JModelList`'s `getItems()` the default method uses `getStart()` which in turn uses your models `getQuery()` to get a count of the number of items returned by your query, via `_getListCount($query)` which in turn calls the particular database adaptors version of `getNumRows()`). That value is used in the calculation in `getStart()`, if you have a large complicated query and don't really need to use the fancy `getStart()` implementation you can just override it in your model (i.e. your version of the `JModelList` class)

e.g. for our components model's for the front end which have rather complicated `$query`'s returned by `getListQuery`, in their most basic implementation they do something similar to this:

```
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->getState('list.start');
}
```

If you don't override it the default JModelList `getStart()` is invoked which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Method to get the starting number of items for the data set.
 *
 * @return  integer  The starting number of items available in the data set.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function getStart()
{
    $store = $this->getStoreId('getstart');

    // Try to load the data from internal storage.
    if (isset($this->cache[$store]))
    {
        return $this->cache[$store];
    }

    $start = $this->getState('list.start');
    $limit = $this->getState('list.limit');
    $total = $this->getTotal();
    if ($start > $total - $limit)
    {
        $start = max(0, (int) (ceil($total / $limit) - 1) * $limit);
    }

    // Add the total to the internal cache.
    $this->cache[$store] = $start;

    return $this->cache[$store];
}
```

But, this probably isn't the problem area, it's more likely in your `populateState()`. **At the end** of `populateState()` you call `parent::populateState()` (if was called at the beginning it wouldn't be overwriting results of your method).

You seem to be duplicating the work done by the parent::populateState() which is probably redundant, looking at `JModelList`'s implementation you will see this:

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
{
    // If the context is set, assume that stateful lists are used.
    if ($this->context)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        $value = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $app->getCfg('list_limit'), 'uint');
        $limit = $value;
        $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

        $value = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
        $limitstart = ($limit != 0 ? (floor($value / $limit) * $limit) : 0);
        $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart);

        // Check if the ordering field is in the white list, otherwise use the incoming value.
        $value = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.ordercol', 'filter_order', $ordering);
        if (!in_array($value, $this->filter_fields))
        {
            $value = $ordering;
            $app->setUserState($this->context . '.ordercol', $value);
        }
        $this->setState('list.ordering', $value);

        // Check if the ordering direction is valid, otherwise use the incoming value.
        $value = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.orderdirn', 'filter_order_Dir', $direction);
        if (!in_array(strtoupper($value), array('ASC', 'DESC', '')))
        {
            $value = $direction;
            $app->setUserState($this->context . '.orderdirn', $value);
        }
        $this->setState('list.direction', $value);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->setState('list.start', 0);
        $this->state->set('list.limit', 0);
    }
}
```

The most obvious condition in the `parent::populateState()` that causes `list.start` to be set to `0` is the very first line, which checks your object `context` value, it may be that something is going wrong there and your objects `context` value is equating to false. (*I can't see `context` defined anywhere... so, it will try an guess/build a `context` value for you in `__construct()`*).

However, it may also be in the way in which getUserSateFromRequest() is processing the values returned from your request, it's hard to tell with the code available.

Comment: Overriding getStart() method solve my problem.But in the middle of pagination I selected page limit as All.It doesn't gives me any result.When I select All as page limit it works well except only above scenario.Seams page limit is set to 0.Then db query will like SELECT* FROM _tebleName LIMIT 0,0.Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Are you still calling the `parent::populateState()` at the end of your  classes version?

Comment: Did you revert the change you made to the core files that you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes I revert the change.The problem seams query Limit set to 0,0.

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like a different issue, if your original problem is solved then by this answer you should mark it so, and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add limit like this `$query->limit('0,40');` in `getListQuery()` function

Comment: I added $query->limit($this->getState('limitstart').','.$this->getState('limit')); and it does not work for me.Do you have any idea.$this->getState('limitstart') and $this->getState('limit') has values according to pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have list_limit defined in your component options? If not, then add a new parameter to your component options and call it list_limit. This will allow you to set your pagination limit to what ever you want in the component options.

Comment: My list_limit is ok.The problem is with limitstart.It always set to 0 when pagination.